# How to verify that a certain character is inside two dedicated characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say that the character we need to target is **$**, and we need to verify if it lies between two **'** & **'**. The code will look something like this :

```
var str = " Verify '$' "
var str2 = " Let's see if ' The $ is inside ! ' "
var str3 = " I got $ "
console.log(verify(str)) //=> true
console.log(verify(str2)) //=> true
console.log(verify(str3)) //=> false
```

Javascript **String.prototype.includes()**, can be used to verify if **$** exists in the string but I am not understanding how to verify if it is inside **'** & **'** ?

Comment: `includes("'$'")` ?

Comment: @Cid I updated the question a little bit, to make it more practical ! As it is not mandatory that '$' is always matched.

Comment: Good point. Are you ease with RegEx ?

Comment: Yep ! I actually love using regex.

Comment: @ArcanadianArc Would `"' Let's see if  The $ is inside ! ' "` count? or are only spaces allowed between the `'` and `$`? How about `"''$'"`?

Comment: @Cid I have an idea. Here we have a string 'str', so we can first use regex to get the content between ' & ', after which we can verify if '$' is contained in it ? Is that a good one ?

Comment: @nick zoum Yes, that's one the major problem I am suffering from. Is there any solution to that ?

Comment: @ArcanadianArc this can be done in one shot. Check the differents answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look for `$`, wrapped by `'`.

```js
const check = string => /'.*\$.*'/.test(string);

console.log([
    " Verify '$' ",
    " Let's see if ' The $ is inside ! ' ",
    " I got $ "].map(check)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Regular Expressions :

```js
function verify(input)
{
  const regex = RegExp(/'.*?\$.*?'/);
  return regex.test(input);
}

var str = " Verify '$' "
var str2 = " Let's see if ' The $ is inside ! ' "
var str3 = " I got $ "
console.log(verify(str)) //=> true
console.log(verify(str2)) //=> true
console.log(verify(str3)) //=> false
```

`/'.*?\$.*?'/` pattern description :

`'` matches the character `'` literally (case sensitive)

`.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*?` Quantifier — Matches between **zero and unlimited times**, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

`\$` matches the character `$` literally (case sensitive)

`.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*?` Quantifier — Matches between **zero and unlimited times**, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

`'` matches the character `'` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: This will return `true` for `" Verify 'a'$' "`

Comment: @nickzoum indeed, since the `$` is between `'`

Comment: The op said in the comments that this should return `false`

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty hard to check if the `$` is indeed between two `'` and not between a pair of `' a '` and `' b 'b`. So I would recommend iterating through the string and toggling a boolean whenever you see a quote. If you find a `$` when the boolean is `true` check if there is a `'` in the rest of the text;

```js
console.log(verify("'$'")) //=> true
console.log(verify("'   $   '")) //=> true
console.log(verify("'a'   $ '")) //=> false
console.log(verify("   '   $ ")) //=> false

function verify(text) {
  var openQuotes = false;
  for (var index = 0; index < text.length; index++) {
    if (text[index] === "'") openQuotes = !openQuotes;
    else if (text[index] === "$" && openQuotes && text.indexOf("'", index) !== -1) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```